# Ng-include is only appearing after the second time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a dialog directive that I'm using in a template. I'm doing something like:

```
<my-dialog>
    <div>
        <ng-include src="'myTemp.html'"></ng-include>
    </div>
<my-dialog>
```

For some weird reason when I open my dialog, nothing appears when it's opened the first time. The second time populates my dialog with myTemp.html. Do I need to do things with $templateCache to notify angular about myTemp.html so that it works the first time?

Sorry I did have the '' around the src, I just forgot to add it for this submission =/.

Comment: Make sure put the right path, and also try src="'myTemp.html'" (notice there is an apostrophe inside).

Comment: what does the code for `myDialog` look like?  it appears that you are trying to transclude the `ng-include` here, meaning that you are trying to insert a template into another template, which generally isn't a good idea.  you *might* be able to fix this if your directive has a lower priority than `ng-include`, but it would be better if the directive accepted the inner template as a parameter and rendered a single template, instead of trying to use transclusion.

Comment: What I'm confused about is that it works perfectly when I had myTemp.html as part of the same template file (the one above). This ng-include problem only surfaced when I moved that template out of this file into a created one.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-include` `src` is expecting a variable, isn't it?
So, I'm guessing that the src in your example should be wrapped in `''`. So, it will be:

```
<ng-include src="'myTemp.html'"></ng-include>
```

See if that helps.

Here's the official documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

Answer (score 1):

src in the ng-include tag expects an expression. so to pass it a string you need to put quote around it:

```
<ng-include src="'myTemp.html'"></ng-include>
```